# How to implement Custom Presenter Rows?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, eureka-forms

I am trying to build a custom presenter row in [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) in swift 3, which when tapped, shows a `UIViewController`.

The [documentation](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#custom-presenter-rows) suggests the following code:

```
public final class CustomPushRow<T: Equatable>: SelectorRow<PushSelectorCell<T>, SelectorViewController<T>>, RowType {

    public required init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
        presentationMode = .show(controllerProvider: ControllerProvider.callback {
            return SelectorViewController<T>(){ _ in }
            }, completionCallback: { vc in
                vc.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        })
    }
}
```

where I will have to replace `SelectorViewController` with `MyViewController`. But right now its giving following error (even without replacing the UIViewController name):

> Cannot convert value of type 'ControllerProvider' to
>   expected argument type 'ControllerProvider<_>'

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Alex I counldn't figure this out :(

Comment: I just ended up using a built in one and manually modifying the view controller in the on load method. Total pain in the butt

Answer (score 2):

why you don't use:

```
<<< ButtonRow("Rows") {
                $0.title = $0.tag
                $0.presentationMode = .segueName(segueName: "YourSegue", onDismiss: nil)
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameter `completionCallback` was changed to `onDismiss` in version 2 of Eureka.